# JIRA authentication using Javascript

Tags: javascript, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to perform basic authentication for JIRA, by using JIRA's REST API.
JIRA's website does provide a CURL command to get this done:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"   
http://example.com/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta
```

When I run this in Chrome, I'm getting the following error:

*Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access*

When I run this code in IE, I'm getting the following response, but I know using * for access control defeats the purpose CORS:

```
 {"self":"https://mypersonaljiraurl.org/jira/rest/api/latest/user?
    username=12345","name":"12345","loginInfo":
    {"failedLoginCount":2,"loginCount":50}}
```

I wrote the following code in Javascript to make a HTTP request.

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "https://mypersonaljiraurl/rest/auth/1/session", false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authenticateUser(userName, passWord));  
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json'); 
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    request.send();
    alert(request.status);
    response.innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

How do I resolve this so it can work in Chrome? Would it be better to do this with Jquery/Ajax?

Comment: I've spent a lot of time researching this issue. Using a reverse proxy to access the jira site has solved my problem!